# wss tornado connection issues

Tags: websocket, tornado, wss

Tornado Server

```
ssl_options = {
        "certfile": "server.crt",
        "keyfile": "server.key"
}
application=Application()
server=tornado.httpserver.HTTPServer(application,xheaders=True,ssl_options=ssl_options)
server.listen(tornado.options.options.port)
tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
```

JS Websocket

```
webSocket = new WebSocket("wss://" + location.hostname + ":8888/socket");
```

The connection does not open, and the open() method is not called, and there is no error either.

When trying with an insecure socket connection from JS

```
webSocket = new WebSocket("ws://" + location.hostname + ":8888/socket");
```

I get the following errors:

```
Tornado:

    [W 140725 11:35:35 iostream:845] SSL Error on 11 ('192.168.0.72', 54554): [Errno 1] _ssl.c:504: error:1407609C:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_CLIENT_HELLO:http request


JS:

    WebSocket connection to 'ws://192.168.0.72:8888/socket' failed: Connection closed before receiving a handshake response
```

However when I remove the ssl_options from tornado, and try and insecure connection from JS, it works fine.

```
Tornado:

    server = tornado.httpserver.HTTPServer(application)

JS:

    webSocket = new WebSocket("ws://" + location.hostname + ":8888/socket");
```

I am unable to figure out what the issue might be and how to proceed.

Answer (score 1):

The browser is probably trying to show you the "do you accept this self-signed certificate" dialog, but can't because the websocket connection is invisible.  To use `wss:` with a self-signed certificate you must first visit a regular html page with that certificate so you can accept it.

Comment: I had already accepted the certificate, the problem was that I was trying to access the webpage over http instead of https. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

The tornado error message means that an http request is being sent to an https port. I was loading the javascript from an http url, changing that to https solved the problem.