# WebSocket connection to self signed server

Tags: python, ssl, https, websocket, tornado

I would like to make connection to my websocket server which i basicly need to be over https.

```
from tornado.options import define, options
from imaplib import Commands
define("port", default=443, help="run on the given port", type=int)

class WebSocketHandler(tornado.websocket.WebSocketHandler):
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(WebSocketHandler, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs);
    pass;
def open(self):
    print 'new connection'
    self.write_message("connected")

def on_message(self, message):
    print 'message received %s' % message
    self.write_message('message received %s' % message)

def on_close(self):
    print 'connection closed'

def check_origin(self, origin):
    return True;

if __name__ == "__main__":
    tornado.options.parse_command_line()
    app = tornado.web.Application(
       handlers=[
           (r"/ws", WebSocketHandler)
       ]
    )
    data_dir = "/home/pi/projects/WebSocketOverHttps/";
    httpServer = tornado.httpserver.HTTPServer(app, ssl_options = {
       "certfile": os.path.join(data_dir, "cert.crt"),
       "keyfile": os.path.join(data_dir, "key.key"),
    });
    httpServer.listen(options.port)
    print "Listening on port:", options.port
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
```

the problem is that my browser says: "WebSocket connection to 'wss://192.168.1.8/ws' failed: WebSocket opening handshake was canceled"

The things what i tried to do was:
1) Add certificate to system (win 8.1 PRO x64) by double clicking on cert file
2) Add certificate to google chrome on the same system (through settings of browser)

I am able to connect to this server when i reimplement it to use http instead of https so physical connection to machine looks OK.

my certificate are self-signed, generated by command:

```
sudo openssl req -x509 -nodes -days 365000 -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout /etc/apache2/ssl/apache.key -out /etc/apache2/ssl/apache.crt
```

this is how i try to connect to it:

```
var socket = new WebSocket("wss://192.168.1.8:443/ws");
```

Comment: What version of Chrome do you have? IIRC, they added the "reject self-signed certs" fix in one version, and added the "share acceptable self-signed certs between wss and https" later, and in between there was basically no way to specify acceptable self-signed certs for wss (with ignoring cert errors globally as the only real workaround).

Comment: Also, I don't think this problem has anything to do with your code. You may want to try (a) searching for similar issues without the python and tornado tags, and (b) seeing if you can reproduce the problem with a generic wss server (e.g., a ws proxy to netcat).

Comment: "38.0.2125.111 m" is version of my Chrome

Comment: This may be a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24949576/wss-tornado-connection-issues. I know you said you added the certificate to chrome manually, but I'm not sure if that does the same thing as accepting the certificate when you visit a page using it.

Comment: @BenDarnell, Youre right. I will place it as answer to my own question.

Answer (score 2):

As @BenDarnell posted, We have to accept this certificate by browse to page of this server. Then your browser will inform that this site is untrusted. Let your browser to use this untrusted certificate and that's all. Here is code you will need to place in code:

```
class MainHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
  def get(self):
    loader = tornado.template.Loader(".")
    self.write(loader.load("index.html").generate());

app = tornado.web.Application(
handlers=[
   (r"/ws", WebSocketHandler),
   (r"/", MainHandler)
])

data_dir = "/home/pi/projects/Something";
ssl_options_dict = {
    "certfile": os.path.join(data_dir, "cert.crt"),
    "keyfile": os.path.join(data_dir, "key.key"),
};

httpServer = tornado.httpserver.HTTPServer(app, ssl_options = ssl_options_dict);
```