# How to use secure websocket (wss) in Tornado

Tags: qt, websocket, tornado

I'm new to Tornado and web services in general. In my application, I've Qt/c++ client and python Tornado on server side. The Qt client sends commands in the form of text messages(e.g. "ws://192.121.1.213:8080?*function*=myfunction?*args*=params..").Now, I want to use secure web socket i.e. **wss** in stead of **ws**. What changes are required on server and client side? Pointer to any online example would be also helpful. Thanks.

Comment: can somebody help me out. This is bit urgent. I've tried to find an example on web but couldn't find the relevant example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pass the `ssl_options` argument when constructing your `HTTPServer`:

```
ssl_ctx = ssl.create_default_context(ssl.Purpose.CLIENT_AUTH)
ssl_ctx.load_cert_chain(os.path.join(data_dir, "mydomain.crt"),
                        os.path.join(data_dir, "mydomain.key"))
HTTPServer(applicaton, ssl_options=ssl_ctx)
```

http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/httpserver.html#http-server

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I made the changes to on server side as given in the example. Also, I changed the query to "wss://192.121.1.213:8080?function=myfunction?args=params.." (wss instead of ws). But it seems that this simple doesn't connect to server. How should I frame the query?

Comment: Hard to say without more detail, but my guess is that you're using a self-signed certificate and need to accept it in the browser first: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24949576/wss-tornado-connection-issues